# How to echo innertext using Simple HTML dom parser

Tags: php, parsing

HTML Source Code:

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Middle_RatingSummary1_Rating1_RatingPanel">
<img id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Middle_RatingSummary1_Rating1_RatingImage" title="(2.5 / 5)  : Above Average" src="../../../../../images/net/common/stars/transparent/2.5.png" alt="(2.5 / 5)  : Above Average" style="border-width:0px;" />
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Middle_RatingSummary1_Rating1_RatingText" class="text med strong">(2.5 / 5)  : Above Average</span>
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Middle_RatingSummary1_Rating1_RatingHelp" class="help"></a>
```

I want Output like this:

```
(2.5 / 5)  : Above Average
```

I tried it, but not Getting it:

Php code:

```
$ratings = $html->find('div[id=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder_Middle_RatingSummary1_Rating1_RatingPanel] span')->outertext;

echo "$ratings[0]";
```

Comment: what is `$html`? what class etc.

Comment: you are not trying to generate and get a html code in the same PHP file right? Can you better explain `$html` class/object?
Also: I'm not sure if you just omitted it, but did you close the `div` tag?

Comment: $html = file_get_html('http://www.nowrunning.com/movie/10811/tamil/thalaiva/4355/review.htm');

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you write

```
echo "something_here"
```

You'll get as output

```
something_here
```

even if `something_here` is a variable. If you want to print a variable, don't put it inside `""`

Now, instead of

```
$ratings = $html->find('div[id=...] span')->outertext;
echo "$ratings[0]";
```

Try doing

```
$ratings = $html->find('div[id=...] span');
echo $ratings[0]->outertext;
```

Besides, you probably want `innertext` instead of `outertext`